# Does powerbi embedded in azure not have a portal to manage workspaces, reports, etc?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I just created a powerbi embedded resource (A1 sku) in azure. It created a capacity, but I don’t see a way to get to the “portal” where I can manage workspaces - eg create workspace, upload pix, etc from the browser. I realize I can use pbi rest apis to achieve this but it is very cumbersome to do even simple operations, esp for data analysts.

Is this functionality not included with powerbi embedded A1 sku? Do I need the EM or P sku perhaps? Or I am missing something really basic.

Comment: This is done in [Power BI Service](https://app.powerbi.com).

Comment: But does the Tenant have subscribed to an Office365 E3 or E5 SKU? Without that, I believe just creating a A1 SKU doesnt work... correct?

Comment: You don't need to buy E3 or E5. You can buy single Power BI Pro license, or even use Power BI Free (which makes no sense though).

Answer (score 2):

For Power BI Embedded (and Premium), you still use the normal Power BI Service and experience, however you need to allocate the workspace to capacity. Embedded is not a portal in itself, it is an extension to the service.
You can do this in two ways, from the admin portal under capacity, or directly in the workspace, under the workspace settings > advanced section.

Once the workspace is allocated it gets a diamond icon next to the workspace. The MS docs has the full details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-premium-manage#assign-a-workspace-to-a-capacity)

Comment: Thanks, but I believe the tenant also has to have subscribed to Office 365 E3 or E5 SKUs, right?

Comment: EM and P skus are purchased via O365 tenancy admin portal, you can have just Power BI and not all the O365 tools the admin portal is still the same for the high level tenancy options, A skus are purchased via azure